# Finding deployment data to a SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment

In an effort to maintain versions of the databases we have in our CMDB, I have to obtain the versions of some databases deployed to our servers by a third party company.

Is there a system table, view or procedure that allows me to view information regarding recent deployments (code changes from an update script) to a SQL database?

Comment: Define "recent deployments to a SQL database". Do you want the version of each individual database or some version number maintained by a third party?

Comment: This is to do with a single database. I want information such as the date of deployment and what was deployed.

Comment: What do you mean with deployment? Is it when the third party deploys new code to a database or when the server itself was installed and setup?

Comment: Sorry, allow me clarify. What I mean by deployment in this instance is code changes to an existing database such as table updates or added stored procedures/views.

Comment: By default: I don't think so. You can achieve this by using DDL Triggers

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](http://izlooite.blogspot.in/2010/12/sql-server-how-to-find-user-who-last.html), additionally there is also always the [Auditing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc280386.aspx) feature in SQLServer that you can have a look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options.

First, you can build your own logging based on a table and a ddl trigger which will log each change in any procedure etc.

Second, you can track changes in one of this sys tables:

```
select * from sys.all_sql_modules -- Get the sourcecode of each proc (and track it)
select * from sys.objects -- Get information which object is modified at which date
```

Third, you can reverse engineer changes in the recent past by reading the trace log of the sql server itself and filter for drop/create events. (needed SA permission)

```
-- Get the current server trace file 
select * 
from fn_trace_getinfo(NULL)
where property=2
and traceid = 1

-- Copy value from the query above and paste it here
select * 
from fn_trace_gettable('[PASTE PATH HERE!]', -1) 
where EventClass IN(46,47) -- Create/Drop Object
```

Hopefully there is one solution for you which is helpfully for you.

But by the way. Another idea is, if your workflow allows this. Just use SSDT to create deployment packages and keep track of your changes.

Best regards,
Ionic

Comment: The second solution was what solved the problem for me, thanks very much!

Comment: No problemo. Btw.if you just need the routine definition, you can use the information_schema which is more robust on migrations.

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES -- Column Routine_Definition